# How to make a checkerboard of JButtons

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton

I need to make a checkerboard that is composed of alternating black and white JButtons, that are right up against another. Can I use the graphics class to add buttons? I would appreciate help not answer as this is homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) you can find examples on how to use it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html). Lastly, I think that using JPanels will give you a better finish than using JButtons if you want to create a checkered board, but that is entirely up to you.

Comment: Good call on the `GridLayout`.  OTOH 1) It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).  Please roll it back if you disagree. Otherwise, vote for the RFE.  ;)
 2) Adding buttons to a GL can be just as visually nice, and are a lot easier to work with, than re-implementing button functionality within paint.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I agree with the latest version of the docs. By default, if you will, I tend to revert to the previous ones since these are the ones I used to use myself.

Comment: Unfortunately, a default search in 'a major search engine' will point to the 1.4.2 docs.  I guess it is because the weight of links on the net still favors 1.4.  It is not about to change unless (Oracle implements my RFE or) we all laboriously drag the search engines from version to version by posting updated links.  :(

Comment: [Extended Commercial support](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) for 1.4.2 ends soon, so the heat is on. Also consider `MyButton extends JToggleButton implements Icon`.